# Company supplied data list, with customer additions

Tags: database-design

Imagine a company/supplier supplied table of items

```
table - blueprints
 id [pk]
 name
 color

blueprints
- 1 - chair - pink
- 2 - table - blue
```

As a company we would supply blueprints as a global list,
the customer would have a local copy of that list.

The customer would need to add more blueprints which would add rows to their local copy (which is a bad idea)
Occasionally as the company/supplier would have additions to the blueprints table.
Ideally after several iterations of updates from the supplier, it would be nice that across all customers the supplied blueprint list has the same id across all customers.

Im sure this is know problem, or there is a better solution for this.
Any thoughts / ideas / existing posts / explanations of what this is, with a proper solution?

Comment: Are there properties that would define a *unique* blueprint?  `(Name,Color)` or does it go beyond that?

Comment: Sorry that was just generic data, there would be many other things. I figured that got the jist of it out. and thank you for asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of the customer having a local copy and the supplier having the master copy you could have two tables...

## Supplier's Master Copy

### blueprints_master

~**id** ~ **name** ~ **colour** ~
~ 1 ~ chair   ~  pink    ~
~ 2 ~ table   ~  blue    ~

## Customer Local Copy

### blueprints_customer

~**id** ~ **name** ~ **colour** ~ **blueprits_master_id** ~
~ 1 ~ chair   ~hot pink~  1                                 ~
~ 2 ~ desk   ~ wood   ~   *null*                            ~

## Problems Solved

- A list of blue prints the customer can add, remove, and update
- A link (foreign key) between a customers blueprint and a master blueprint
  - I think this is useful in case the customer want's to "change" one of the master blueprints. Internally the system will create a new entry in the *_cusomter* table rather then changing the *_master* table, but the customer will still feel like they are doing what they wanted
- A list of blueprints the supplier has absolute control over

## Problems Remaining

- Syncing the *_customer* and *_master* tables.

unfortunately I do not have any proposed solution to the syncing problem nor can I reference to any other post...

Comment: Beautiful, I knew there needed to be more then 1 key. But my brain was wrapping it in a different direction.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server has a replication feature that can go from prime --> sub or  also both directions. It can be scary to plan it out, but I've used it in test cases and it worked fine. It might be worth looking into those tools. Also wanted to throw the idea of version numbers in there, for when a customer wants to make a change, without adding a whole new blueprint

Comment: That sounds like a handy feature i didn't even know existed. Awesome. Also haven't made it that far in the planning cycle to think about versioning.